# method of moments of an uniform distribution

Tags: statistics

Let  $ X_1, ... X_n $ a sample of independent random variables with uniform distribution $(0,$$
\theta 
$$
) $
Find a $ $$
\widehat\theta 
$$
 $ estimator for theta using the method of moments
Thanks

I think using the indicatrix used in this type of problems that can not be derived, but not as used

Answer (score 6):

To find the method of moments, you equate the first $k$ sample moments to the corresponding $k$ population moments. You then solve the resulting system of equations simultaneously.
Here note that the first sample moment when $k=1$ is the sample mean. That is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^1=\bar{X}$. The first population moment is just the expectation of Uniform$(0,\theta)$, which is given by $\mathrm{E}(X_i)=\theta/2$.
So the method of moments estimator is the solution to the equation $$\frac{\hat{\theta}}{2}=\bar{X}.$$

Comment: sorry i wanted the estimator of maximun verisimilitude )=

Comment: Do you mean the MLE?

Comment: yes, i mean the MLE :D

Comment: oh ok. could you post it as a different question then (Since the above question deals with the method of methods). I'll do my best to help...:)

Answer (score 3):

Just set the empirical average $\bar X$ equal to $E[X_1] = \frac \theta 2$. This gives $\hat \theta = 2 \bar X$, correct?